# Objective c cancelAllLocalNotifications doesn't work when app was in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

Works in all cases except, when the App was running in the background and then launched by the user clicking on the notification, the app starts, the notification is shown with, but the clear doesn't work!

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
NSDictionary *notificationPayload = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if(notificationPayload) {
        [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:notificationPayload];
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if([[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"] != nil) {
        NSString *message = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];
        if(message != nil) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Usage Alert"
            message:message  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
            [alertView show];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
        }
    }

}
```